# Throttle multiple-user requests to external site PHP?

Tags: php, api, external, throttling

I currently have a script that, in part, sends requests to an external site. The external site has a simple API limit of 50 per 30 seconds for using the API, and if it sends a specific type of request to the main site (like my script will do), it's 3 per minute. Now, this is easy to solve for one user using the script. However, multiple users will be using the script at the same time, and if enough users use it at the same time, the limit will go over. I am trying to throttle multiple-user requests to keep my server from sending more than the limit even though each user isn't. I'm trying to figure out a way to do so. Ensuring that the server never sends too many requests to the external site. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use some global sync flag, like `memcache` record or semaphore: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php

Comment: save the requests in a database. Fire them 3 per minute at the external site using a cron script.

Comment: or better yet use a real queuing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [token bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) with a shared storage for rate limiting. I implemented one for you: [bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket)

This example will limit the rate for all users to 50 requests per 30 seconds (i.e. 100 requests per minute):

```
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\Rate;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\TokenBucket;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\storage\FileStorage;

$storage = new FileStorage(__DIR__ . "/api.bucket");
$rate    = new Rate(100, Rate::MINUTE);
$bucket  = new TokenBucket(50, $rate, $storage);
$bucket->bootstrap(50);

if (!$bucket->consume(1, $seconds)) {
    http_response_code(429);
    header(sprintf("Retry-After: %d", floor($seconds)));
    exit();
}
```